# Systemcrash suexec forkbomb.sh ulimits

Tags: centos, process, process-management, cgroups, ulimit

I got this script named fork.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
forkbomb() { forkbomb | forkbomb & } ; forkbomb
```

If I call it through suexec my whole system will consume 99% cpu. 
To prevent a normal bash forkbomb I used the limits.conf and set nproc to 50. 
This works as expected.

But if I call the above mentioned script through suexec over httpd, I see in top over 6000 tasks and a sys cpu use >97%. I can see multiple entries of user3 fork.sh with ~ 0,6% cpu. 
If I call systemd-cgtop the system.slice have 100% cpu and system.slice/httpd.service 75%

I restricted httpd with cgroups:

```
 systemctl set-property --runtime httpd.service CPUShares=600 MemoryLimit=500M
```

I don't get it, why ulimits and cgroups will not handle this issue.

Comment: Are you running it via http through suexec so that it runs as `root`? Or are you going via root through suexec to run as `http`? If it's the former: the problem is `/etc/limit.d/90-nproc.conf` probably exists and does so for a good reason. If you restrict the number of processes runnable as root, you can essentially shut yourself out of the system.

Comment: no  i don't restrict root. suexec runs for user3 and i defined a group sshusers and restricted this group in /etc/limit.d/20-nproc.conf like this: @sshusers nproc 50. user3 has a vhost config i call with lynx user3.com/cgi-bin/fork.sh. i think httpd get to much requests or something like this.

Comment: I forgot something very important. See answer

Comment: i can't see your answer? For information my setup is the following: multiple vhosts with seperated system users for php-fpm and suexec. each vhost have a seperated homedir which is used as documentroot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `limits` files are utilized by `PAM`. The stock `suexec` provided by apache still does not recognize or utilize `PAM`. [Patches exist.](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-apache@lists.debian.org/msg11921.html) And you can modify the source directly to invoke `setrlimit` (it looks pretty easy - see the `setlimit(2)` man page.) But as is, `suexec` will not recognize anything you do with `limits`.

You can still set ulimits from within apache, but I think this is undesirable, especially in the pre-fork model, because then you limit the load your http server can handle. Further, I'm not sure if limits will carry over to the `suexec` environment because I'm not sure how `suexec` does its job.

The reason `CPUShares` won't help you here is because your fork bomb is a resource hog, but the resources aren't really in the userland CPU cycles. By the time CPU accounting becomes involved, it's too late: your system has no free memory or process slots to try to run the program.

You might try `prlimit`, part of `util-linux` so it should be standard with your installation.  If you do this:

```
$ prlimit --nproc=1 bash -c bash -c id

bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

So the little 2-fork process failed.

Unfortunately, I don't see a sound way you can get prlimit involved in the execution chain. Apache has screwed themselves and all of us by providing a deprecated `suexec` module that isn't flexible enough to meet the basic demand, and is straight-jacketed enough that any real solution requires blasting a hole through security.

Comment: ok then the best solution is to patch apache? iam on a centos system, there is no setrlimit installed. is there no way to restrict it with systemd and cgroups? To ulimit the apache user is no alternative, i know.

Comment: `setrlimit` is a system call. We're talking about patching at source level and compiling. For `suexec` itself, that's pretty trivial, since it's a small program. However, it's packaged with apache web server's sources. All things considered, it's better to try to apply the PAM patch for suexec.

With `systemd` you get all that is documented in `systemd.resource-control` which isn't much. The more I look at `systemd` the less I like it: bloatware doesn't suit Linux. At least it's not `upstart`. 

Maybe `prlimit` is the way to do this. Revising answer.

Comment: Can I assume you're trying to make a web-server environment for a multi-user group and granting users the ability to run CGI within their own context? And further, trying to have some sane guarantee that said users wont run your system out of resources?

Comment: ok thx. yes your right with your assume.

Comment: In that case, the better answer might be: run an HTTP instance for each user, and toss out the use of suexec altogether. As long as your users are under 20 or so, this solution has some nice properties: You as the sysadmin can use systemd as above to control the CPU shares of each user's HTTP process-tree. The users will have the ability to have near complete control over the HTTP environment -- with some restrictions.  The way to do this would be to set up a reverse proxy/load-balancer that handles all inbound requests and directs them to each user's HTTP running on its own port.